# In my Spring 3.2 MVC application, why aren't my JSP EL expressions being evaluated after login?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp

I want to implement spring3.2.0 web mvc following the example: http://programmersplanet.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/4/

but I fail. Finally I get the result which is: `Successfully logged in: ${user.username}`, you see the variable is useless(JSP doesn't work).  I add some output to debug, it proves @Controller, @RequestMapping work. So I don't know what is wrong with my coding.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="demo.spring"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

LoginController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLoginView() {
        UserForm userForm = new UserForm();
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
        view.addObject(userForm);
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") UserForm user, BindingResult bindingResult, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());// this line is right.
        return model;
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
Successfully logged in: ${user.username}
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app
```

Comment: Could you please post your web.xml ?

Comment: Thanks I edit the post and add my web.xml. can you tell me what is wrong in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable cause of your issue is  you have added "userForm" in your Controller and trying to access it as ${user.username} in JSP !

Also check if you have disabled EL expressing in your web.xml. We have 1000's of user who are relying on Spring MVC, which is the most reliable Java EE framework till date.

Comment: thanks. I modify my web.xml, it works now: <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Answer (score 0):

my web.xml is generated by maven automatically. it is wrong.

Before modification(by default):

`<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
            "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
            "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >`

After modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```